# Why does my class declared list become empty when used in another method than the one where it has been filled

Tags: asp.net, list, methods, count

I declared my list "lijstBijlagen" at the top of my class so I would be able to use it in all the methods of that class. Now the problem is that I fill this list up in the method "btnUpload_Click" but when I want to use it in the method btnSubmit_Click it becomes empty again. I left out my Page_Load code in the code underneath this text because I don't think you'll need it to solve the problem.

```
namespace Veiligheidsplan.WebUI
{
    public partial class MailPage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private List<string> lijstBijlagen = new List<string>(); 


    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> parts = txtOntvangers.Text.Split(',').Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList();
        MailService.SendMail(parts, txtOnderwerp.Text, txtBody.Text, lijstBijlagen);
        Server.Transfer("Homepage.aspx");
    }



    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string bijlage = ddlBijlagen.SelectedItem.Text;
        string bijlagePad = "~/Veiligheidsplan/" + Session["IngelogdeGebruikersnaam"]+"/" + bijlage;
        lijstBijlagen.Add(bijlagePad);
        lblCommentaar.Visible = true;
        lblCommentaar.Text += ", "+bijlage;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You will need to persist your list every postback.
                                                                                                               [image]